# Is every presheaf the colimit of its representable subobjects?

Tags: category-theory

By the usual Kan extension argument, every presheaf $P \in \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{\operatorname{op}}}$ is the colimit of the representables which map into it in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{\operatorname{op}}}$. To recover $P$ as this colimit, does it suffices to restrict to just the representable subobjects of $P$ instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.

Let $G$ be a nontrivial group, viewed as a category with one object. Then:

- a presheaf on $G$ is simply a set with a right action by $G$.
- every representable presheaf is isomorphic to the Cayley representation: $G$ acting on itself by multiplication.

Let $P$ be the action of $G$ on the one-element set.

$P$ doesn't have *any* representable subobjects. And since $P$ isn't initial, it cannot be written as a colimit of representable subobjects.